# android studio OnClicklistener no reaction on first Click

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

Hello my OnClicklistener does not get the first Click although i can hear the Click sound when i try it. I just searched for a solution but i have not found one that works for me.

XML

```
 <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/ButtonNO"
    android:onClick="KlickNo"
    android:id="@+id/NoKlickKopf"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5" />
```

Java

public void KlickYes(View view) {

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YesKlickKopf);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            frage = frage + 1;

            switch (frage) {

                case 1: //error

                    break;
                case 2: //error

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}

public void KlickNo (View view) {
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NoKlickKopf);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewkopffrage);
        final TextView tTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texttrivakskopf);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frage = frage + 1;

            switch (frage) {

                case 1: //error


                    break;
                case 2: //error

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: it's less work if you just remove the onClick line from your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you do in this code is that you first set an onClickListener through the xml to run the method`void KlickNo (View view)`

and then you cancel all this by setting a `new OnClickListener(){ blah,blah}` replacing the previous setting

You either have to use one or the other.
The KlickNo method is called by the OnClick of the set by xml OnCLickListener, so do your stuff directly there and delete the .setOnClickListener(.....) declaration

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this wrong. You already have defined the onClick in your xml. You DO NOT have to make an onclick listener on inside the KlickNo function. Simply write the code that you want to execute, i.e. **REMOVE THE BUTTON DECLARATION and the onclicklistener** from KickNo.