# Android switch statement is not working correctly

Tags: android, switch-statement, case

I have an imageview that i use as a button, i set up an onclick method and inside it i declared a switch statement, i need every time i click the button i should call a different case, so i set up case 0, case 1, case 2, case 3, and i put the methods that i want for each case, however, everytime i click the button, the cases seems to mix up together, it calls only case 0 and case 3, i don't know what is wrong, i use this code on an older project and it worked well but now i can't see what's going wrong.

Here's my code:

```
 // i tried to use static, final int but still it's the same problem.
 private int textnumber = 0;
 button_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (textnumber) {

        case 0:
            //changeTextColor(int) method, for each number it changes the text's color.
            changeTextColor(1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text color is 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            changeTextColor(2);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text color is 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            changeTextColor(3);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text color is 3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 3:
            changeTextColor(4);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text color is 4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }

        }
    });

 private void changeTextColor(int id){
    //mRenderer is a class that uses GLES 2.0 (glsurfaceview etc...);
    //mObjectsData is a class that i use to store different datas
    if(id == 1){
    textnumber = 1;
    mObjectsData.mTextColor = "yellow";
    mRenderer.requestRender();
    }
    else if(id == 2){
        textnumber = 2;
        mObjectsData.mTextColor = "green";
        mRenderer.requestRender();
    }
    else if(id == 3){
        textnumber = 3;
        mObjectsData.mTextColor = "blue";
        mRenderer.requestRender();
    }
    else if(id == 4){
        textnumber = 4;
        mObjectsData.mTextColor = "red";
        mRenderer.requestRender();
    }
}
```

Comment: does changeTextColor change textnumber variable? Can you show us that code as well?

Comment: @MattWolfe check edits please!

Comment: After one full cycle, your switch will no longer execute, as you set textnumber to 4 in your last else if in changeTextColor(). Could that be the issue here?

Comment: @Levon i don't think that could be the issue, as i have the same code in Eclipse and it works, now i am using Android Studio and now i am experiencing this issue, i can't really figure it out what's the problem, since i use break; after every case and a different case should be called everytime i click the button

Comment: eclipse and android studio don't actually compile your code for running, they use a combination of android build tools to do this. I think you have a bug somewhere else. That being said the above comment is correct, once you get to 4 you won't get any new values. Also, this code could be reduced to just a couple lines.

Comment: @MattWolfe i clearly know that this code can be reduced, as i said, to achieve what i want i tried different methods, in this project i actually try to test before starting to work the project i should create.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you except that you're probably changing the variable somewhere else that you're not realizing. Without seeing all the code it's impossible to tell. The code you have above though does a lot of extra things that are unnecessary and 90% could easily be removed such that you wouldn't need to worry about a switch statement at all (it's not necessary). There is nothing inherent in a switch statement that magically makes it change variables values.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you must be changing your variable textnumber somewhere else. There is nothing magical about a switch statement or android studio that would cause it to change your variable for no reason. P.S. Your code could be reduced considerably to this:

```
 private int textnumber = 0;
 private String[] colors = new String[] { "yellow", "green", "blue","red" };

 //some method
    button_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           int oldColor = textnumber;
           textnumber = (textnumber + 1) % 4;
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text color is " + textnumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           mObjectsData.mTextColor = colors[oldColor];
           mRenderer.requestRender();

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made the same mistake like me. Look in my old question

[android studio OnClicklistener no reaction on first Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163203/android-studio-onclicklistener-no-reaction-on-first-click)

My mistake was to set the onclicklistener and declare the button. I should have made only one thing.

Comment: i use only src, width, height, and id inside the .xml layout